# CSS horizontal scroll (simple)

Tags: css, scrollbar

Given:

```
        <div class="pageNavWrap">
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">1</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">2</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">3</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">4</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">5</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">6</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">7</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">8</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">9</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">10</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">11</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">12</a>
            <a class="pageLink" href="#">13</a>
        </div>
```

With:

```
.pageNavWrap{
    background-color:#666;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
a.pageLink{
    color:White;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

How can I stop the links overflowing downwards?  I would like them to overflow-x only (already specified in CSS) so that the horizontal scroll bar comes into play.

Cheers!

Comment: You need to give the div a width

Comment: @sunn The div is occupying the remaining space available in it's container, this is not possible unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Browsers don't all seem to agree about inheritance on this attribute so try adding it to both css rules.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding display:inline to the a.pageLink class

Answer (score 0):

[Overflow-x](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow) might not be the best option as we are still waiting for all browsers to adopt all CSS3 features.

From a user experience point of view, do you really need the 13 (or more) pagination results? If you decide yes, then I would consider making your pagination results into a list and left-float the li's with a css declaration display:inline;

To force your list to always appear on one line, consider [white-space:nowrap](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not picky about browser compatibility:

```
.pageNavWrap
{
  display: table-row;
}
.pageLink
{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

and I was going to suggest `white-space: nowrap;` as well but @Noel Walters beat me to it.